# Routing with Link is not working with const component react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want a link in the but then i dont know how to i use it with **const**
with class it works. can anyone please explain about const components

```
                import React from 'react';
            import { connect } from 'react-redux';
            import { Link } from 'react-router';

            const mapStateToProps=  state =>{
                return { articles :state.articles};
            }
            const connectedList = ({ articles }) =>(
                articles.map(e=>(
                    <li key={e.id}>{e.title}</li>
                ))
                <Link to="/Form">Form</Link>//// this line is error thrown
            );

            const List= connect(mapStateToProps)(connectedList);
            export default List;
```

I know I'm do it the wrong way as i have no idea how do i achieve it the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax errors. Most importantly, your "connectedList" didn't actually return/render anything.

You would have run into other problems because you hadn't wrapped your array of `<li>`s into a `<ul>`, but also, a React component `render` expects there to be only a single element at the top-level -- which is why I wrapped everything in a `<div>`.

I've cleaned up some items for clarity and used a React class instead of a functional component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { articles } = this.props
    const articleListItems = articles.map(article => {
      return <li key={article.id}>{article.title}</li>
    })
    return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {articleListItems}
          </ul>
          <Link to="/Form">Form</Link>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    articles: state.articles
  }
}

const ListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(List)
export default ListContainer
```

Comment: I get the error ./src/components/List.js
Attempted import error: 'Link' is not exported from 'react-router'.

Comment: exported react-router-dom

Comment: @Tested, have you tried: import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'